# How to stop cardano-node from the CLI?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

What is the command or process to gracefully stop a cardano-node instance from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you started the node. If it was started as a systemd service, you'd run the following: `sudo systemctl stop <NODE_SERVICE_NAME>`

If the node was started using the raw cli command `cardano-node run`, then you can just run `ctrl-c` in the same terminal that the node is running in, and it will perform a graceful shutdown.